# Elasticsearch - Edit distance using fuzzy is inaccurate

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 5.5 and my requirement is to allow upto two edits while matching a field.

In ES,I have value as **124456788** and query comes in as **123456789**

```
"fuzzy": {
                            "idkey": {
                                "value": **"123456789"**,
                                "fuzziness": "20"

                            }
                        }
```

To my knowledge the edit distance is 2 between these two numbers. But it is not matching even with fuzziness property as 20.

I did an explain api call and here is what I am seeing

```
"description": "no match on required clause (((idkey:012345789)^0.7777778 (idkey:012346789)^0.7777778 (idkey:013456789)^0.7777778 (idkey:023456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:102345678)^0.7777778 (idkey:112345678)^0.7777778 (idkey:113456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:120456589)^0.7777778 (idkey:121345678)^0.7777778 (idkey:122345678)^0.7777778 (idkey:122345679)^0.7777778 (idkey:122456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123006789)^0.7777778 (idkey:123045678)^0.7777778 (idkey:123096789)^0.7777778 (idkey:123106789)^0.7777778 (idkey:123145678)^0.7777778 (idkey:123146789)^0.7777778 (idkey:123226789)^0.7777778 (idkey:123256789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123345678)^0.7777778 (idkey:123345689)^0.7777778 (idkey:123346789)^0.7777778 (idkey:123406784)^0.7777778 (idkey:123415678)^0.7777778 (idkey:123435678)^0.7777778 (idkey:123446789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123453789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123454789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123455789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456289)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456489)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456709)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456779)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456780)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456781)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456783)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456785)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456786)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456787)^0.8888889 (idkey:123456889)^0.8888889 (idkey:123457789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123466789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123496789)^0.8888889 (idkey:123556789)^0.8888889 (idkey:126456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:223456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:423456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:623456789)^0.8888889 (idkey:723456789)^0.8888889)^5.0)",
```

The value I am expecting to match is 124456788 but ES query is internally not converting it as one of the possible match parameter in fuzzy query.

Do i need to use different ES method to make this work?

Comment: How have you inserted your data into the server?

Answer (score 0):

This a simple indexing and search.

```
PUT /myIndex/type1/1
{
    "key":"123456789",
    "name":"test"
}

GET /myIndex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "key": {
                "value": "124456799",
                "fuzziness": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is always matching with the given key. `fuzziness` values 2 or greater is fine.

Comment: Thank You.It works with this queyr but not in my index.I am checking my index settings n mappings.I think something wrong there.

Comment: Sure.. If you could share the mapping in the question.